# IntersectionObserver change class

Tags: javascript, css

this is my html code:

```
<table class="master"><thead><tr><td>Test</td></tr></thead><tbody>...</tbody></table>
```

if master gets sticky i like to add a class to each td in thead.

This is my code to check if master is sticky:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            const el = document.querySelector('.blanks-table')
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
              ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle('stick', e.intersectionRatio < 1),
              { threshold: [1] }
            );
            
            observer.observe(el);
        });
```

But this changes table class to "master stick" but i like to change the corresponding td in thead. How can i toggle the td?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just search for the `td` elements inside the `e.target` element with e.g. `querySelectorAll()`([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and apply the class change to each?